# ObjectInputStream throws EOFException on client-server setup

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

I am creating a client and server setup in order to send then server a command and then receive a reply. However when I run it the client throws and EOFException. I understand this is an end of file exception but I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or how I can fix it.

Code for Server:

```
public class Server {

private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

//SET UP AND RUN SERVER
public void startRunning() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
        while (true) {
            try {
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                whileRunning();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                closeAll();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//DURING RUN
private void whileRunning() throws IOException {
    String message = "You are now connected";
    sendMessage(message);
    System.out.println("Connected to client");

}

//WAIT FOR CONNECTION THEN DISPLAYS INFO
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Waiting for connection.....");
    connection = server.accept();
    System.out.println("Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
}

//SETS UP STREAMS
private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
}

//SEND MESSAGE TO CLIENT
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
        output.flush();
        System.out.println("SERVER - " + message);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Can't send message");
    }
}

//CLOSE STREAMS AND SOCKETS
private void closeAll() {
    System.out.println("Closing Connections");
    try {
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Code for starting the server:

```
public class RunServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.startRunning();
}

}
```

Code for client:

```
public class Client {

private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private String message = "";
private String serverIP;
private Socket connection;

public Client(String host) {
    serverIP = host;
}

public void startRunning() {
    try {
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
        whileRunning();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        closeAll();
    }
}

// CONNECT TO SERVER
public void connectToServer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Attempted connection...");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
    System.out.println("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());       
}

// SET UP STREAMS
private void setupStreams() throws IOException {            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("\nStreams Connected");
}

// WHILE CHATTING
private void whileRunning() throws IOException {
    do {
        try {
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            System.out.println(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //In to view exception
            System.out.println("Unable to get message");
            System.exit(0); //In to stop it looping forever (Known issue)
        }
    } while (!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
}

// CLOSE STREAMS AND SOCKETS
public void closeAll() {
    System.out.println("Closing sockets, closing streams");
    try {
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

}
```

Code for starting the client:

```
public class RunClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = new Client("localhost");
    client.startRunning();
}

}
```

When I run the client it constantly loops saying "Unable to get message" forever.
However when I view the exception and exit the code (as added in) I get this problem:

```
 Attempted connection...
Connected to: localhost

Streams Connected
SERVER - You are now connected
java.io.EOFException
    Unable to get message
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at main.Client.whileRunning(Client.java:53)
    at main.Client.startRunning(Client.java:26)
    at main.RunClient.main(RunClient.java:7)
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Most likely an exception was thrown, you caught it here: ` } catch (Exception e) {

            }` and then closed the connection in the `finally` block.  Never suppress exceptions like this; it is generally always the wrong thing to do.  At a minimum you want to log it somewhere so you aren't wondering what happened.  If you can't actually handle the exception, don't catch it.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to catch it to avoid it crashing the program, I'm just not sure how to then deal with it and actually receive data from the serve properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EOFException` is thrown when you get to the end of the stream, which happens when the peer closes the connection.

You need to catch it separately and not treat it as an error.

I also suggest you change `System.exit(0);` to `break;`.

Comment: Ahh okay, how would you suggest I go about treating it so I am able to stop trying to read messages when the peer closes the connection? I'm a bit confused about how I would do it. Thanks for this answer by the way

Comment: Catch the exception and break.